# BERT embeddings in batches

Tags: pytorch, bert-language-model

I am following [this post](http://mccormickml.com/2019/05/14/BERT-word-embeddings-tutorial/) to extract embeddings for sentences and for a single sentence the steps are described as follows:

```
    text = "After stealing money from the bank vault, the bank robber was seen " \
           "fishing on the Mississippi river bank."
    
    # Add the special tokens. 
    marked_text = "[CLS] " + text + " [SEP]"
    
    # Split the sentence into tokens. 
    tokenized_text = tokenizer.tokenize(marked_text)
    
    # Mark each of the 22 tokens as belonging to sentence "1". 
    segments_ids = [1] * len(tokenized_text)
    
    # Convert inputs to PyTorch tensors 
    tokens_tensor = torch.tensor([indexed_tokens]) 
    segments_tensors = torch.tensor([segments_ids])
    
    # Load pre-trained model (weights) 
    model = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased',
                                 output_hidden_states = True,
                                      )
    
    # Put the model in "evaluation" mode, meaning feed-forward operation. 
    model.eval()
    
    with torch.no_grad():
        outputs = model(tokens_tensor, segments_tensors)
        hidden_states = outputs[2]
```

And I want to do this for a batch of sequences. Here is my example code:

```
seql = ['this is an example', 'today was sunny and', 'today was']
encoded = [tokenizer.encode(seq, max_length=5, pad_to_max_length=True) for seq in seql]

encoded
[[2, 2511, 1840, 3251, 3], 
 [2, 1663, 2541, 1957, 3], 
 [2, 1663, 2541, 3, 0]]
```

But since I'm working with batches, sequences need to have same length. So I introduce a padding token (3rd sentence) which confuses me about several points:

- What should the segment id for pad_token (0) will be?
- Should I use attention masking when feeding the tensors to the model so that padding is ignored? In the example only token and segment tensors are used.

  ```
  outputs = model(tokens_tensor, segments_tensors)
  ```
- If I don't work with batches but with individual sentences, then I might not need a padding token. Would it be better to do that compared to batches?

Answer (score 1):

You could do all the work you need using one function ( padding,truncation)

> **encode_plus**

check the parameters: [the docs](https://huggingface.co/transformers/internal/tokenization_utils.html?highlight=encode_plus#transformers.tokenization_utils_base.PreTrainedTokenizerBase.encode_plus)

The same you could do with a list of sequences

> **batch_encode_plus**

[docs](https://huggingface.co/transformers/internal/tokenization_utils.html?highlight=batch_encode_plus#transformers.tokenization_utils_base.PreTrainedTokenizerBase.batch_encode_plus)

Comment: I was skeptical to use encode_plus since the documentation says it is deprecated.

Comment: [Tonenizer](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/tokenizer.html) object is now a callable and by default it behaves as encode_plus.
if you provide a single example to tokenizer it will behave as encode_plus and if you provide a batch of examples it'll behave like batch_encode_plus. But it remains same behaviour.

Comment: I tested ''tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(seql, max_length=5)''  and it does not pad the shorter sequence

Comment: If you look to the docs padding is by default disabled , you have to set padding parameter to True in the function call.

Comment: tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(seql, add_special_tokens=True, max_length=5, padding=True) sadly this also doesn't work

Comment: In your case you have a fixed max_length , what you need is : tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(seql, add_special_tokens=True, max_length=5, padding="max_length")


 'max_length': Pad to a maximum length specified with the argument max_length.
True or 'longest': Pad to the longest sequence in the batch (or no padding if only a single sequence if provided).

Comment: both padding="max_length" or padding="longest" did not work for me. The only thing that worked was pad_to_max_length=True